# Make An Array Of Strings

Tags: ios, arrays, string, nsstring, nsarray

I have a bunch of strings that are used in my search predicate -- I want to put them into an array and search the array rather than searching them individually because searching them individually is *SLOW*

right now this is how my strings are set up

```
- (NSString *)searchableStringValue {
    NSCharacterSet *invalidSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"1234 "];
    NSString *searchString = [[pro componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:invalidSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    return searchString;
}

- (NSString *)searchableStringValueTwo {
    NSCharacterSet *invalidSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"ȵ"];
    NSString *searchString = [[pro componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:invalidSet] componentsJoinedByString:@"n"];
    return searchString;
}

- (NSString *)searchableStringValueThree {
    NSCharacterSet *invalidSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"ŋ"];
    NSString *searchString = [[pro componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:invalidSet] componentsJoinedByString:@"ng"];
    return searchString;
}

- (NSString *)searchableStringValueFour {
    NSCharacterSet *invalidSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"Ẓ"];
    NSString *searchString = [[pro componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:invalidSet] componentsJoinedByString:@"r"];
    return searchString;
}

- (NSString *)searchableStringValueFive {
    NSCharacterSet *invalidSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"v"];
    NSString *searchString = [[pro componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:invalidSet] componentsJoinedByString:@"w"];
    return searchString;
}

- (NSString *)searchableStringValueSix {
    NSCharacterSet *invalidSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"1234"];
    NSString *searchString = [[pro componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:invalidSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    return searchString;
}

- (NSString *)searchableStringValueSeven {
    NSCharacterSet *invalidSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" "];
    NSString *searchString = [[pro componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:invalidSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    return searchString;
}
```

So I wanna ask whats the best way to put these guys into an array?
And is that even the best thing to do?! or am I just being stupid? Is there a better way to do this?!

edit:

search filter:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(head beginswith[c] %@) OR (pro beginswith[c] %@ OR (searchableStringValue beginswith[c] %@) OR (searchableStringValueTwo beginswith[c] %@) OR (searchableStringValueThree beginswith[c] %@) OR (searchableStringValueFour beginswith[c] %@) OR (searchableStringValueFive beginswith[c] %@) OR (searchableStringValueSix beginswith[c] %@) OR (searchableStringValueSeven beginswith[c] %@))", searchText, searchText, searchText, searchText, searchText, searchText, searchText, searchText, searchText];
    searchResults = [cdh filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
```

Comment: What is `pro`? What is slow? How often are you calling those methods versus using the results?

Comment: Pro is an object in a class I have called Words. 
I updated my question above to include my search predicate -- which shows where I'm using the strings. When typing an entry using Search Bar + Search Bar Display controller the keyboard gets really, really slow; i.e. if I type a "b" the b key will be animated as pressed for about 4 seconds before minimizing letting me type the next letter. I'm only calling them to get results.

Comment: Create an array, put the objects in the array.  Probably simplest is NSMutableArray.  Read the Apple specs on NSArray and NSMutableArray (understanding that NSMutableArray implements all the methods of NSArray as well).

Comment: Can you not create one string from `pro` with all of your different replacements?

Comment: @Wain working...seems still a little slow...is there anyway to make it *snappier* a little. anyway you answered my Q -- add an answer and I'll give it to ya

Comment: @HotLicks I was also asking if this is the proper way to proceed...

Comment: I can say with near certainty that it's not the proper way, but probably that's due to lack of experience as much as anything.

Comment: @Wain write up an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to make so many comparisons. Each one takes an amount of time, and each one is based on a calculated value. The `pro` value is static during that time so it's all wasted effort.

If you can, perform all of the replacements on `pro` and store a single string to search with. Store the string, don't apply all the replacements each time. Recreate this search string when `pro` changes.

If you can't apply all the changes and generate one search string, at least store the search strings and recreate only when `pro` changes.